# Ajax data retrieve from controller

Tags: ajax, codeigniter

Hi i have called the database value in codeigniter controller and computed the values of database and stored in one new variable. So how can i get both the database values and the new variable that I have created in the controller as I want to display all database value and the new computed value in view. Please suggest me.

My controller: welcome

```
<?php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Welcome extends CI_Controller {

public $total;

 public function __construct() {
    parent::__construct();
    $this->load->library('table');
    $this->load->model('product_database');
}

public function index() {
   $data['show_table'] = $this->view_table();
    $this->load->view('welcome_message', $data);
}
public function view_table(){
   $result = $this->product_database->show_all_data();
    if ($result != false) {
        return $result;
    } else {
        return 'Database is empty !';
    } 
}
public function AddtoCart(){



    $id = $this->input->post('product_id');
    $qty = $this->input->post('qty');

    $this->db->where('id', $id); // Select where id matches the posted id
    $query = $this->db->get('productlist', 1); // Select the products where a match is found and limit the query by 1

        foreach ($query->result() as $row)
            {
                    $data = array(
                    'id'      => $id,
                    'qty'     => $qty,
                    'price'   => $row->price,
                    'name'    => $row->name

                );
                $total=$qty*$row->price;
                echo $total;


            }



        }

}
?>
```

my view: welcome_message

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<title>Product list</title>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet"        href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js">     </script>
<script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js">  </script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
$("#add").click(function(event) {
event.preventDefault();


jQuery.ajax({
type: "POST",
url: "<?php echo base_url(); ?>" + "index.php/Welcome/AddtoCart",
dataType: 'json',
data: {name: },
success: function(res) {

if (res)
{  alert();
// Show Entered Value

jQuery("#total").html(res.total);

}
}
});
});
});
</script>
</head>
<body>

<div class="container">
<div class="message">
            <?php
            if (isset($read_set_value)) {
                echo $read_set_value;
            }
            if (isset($message_display)) {
                echo $message_display;
            }
            ?>
        </div>
<div> <?php
        if (isset($show_table)) {
            echo "<div class='productlist'>";
            if ($show_table == 'Database is empty !') {
                echo $show_table;
            } else {

                echo '<h2>Product List</h2><br/><br/>';
                ?>
                <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-8">
                <div class="well">

                            <div class="table-responsive">
                <?php
                echo "<table width='98%',  >";
                echo '<tr><th class="e_id">Id</th><th>ProductName</th>     <th>Price</th> <tr/>';
                $i=1;
                foreach ($show_table as $value) {
                    ?> 
                    <tr class="well" >

                        <?php
                        echo  "<td width='30%' height='27px'>" . $value->id . "</td>" . "<td width='70%' height='27px'>" . $value->name . "</td>" . "<td height='27px'>" . $value->price . "</td>";
                        ?>
                        <?php echo form_open('/Welcome/AddtoCart'); ?>
                            <td><input type="number" name="qty" value="1" style="width:40px;" min="1" max="99"></td>
                            <input type="hidden" name="product_id" value="<?php echo $value->id ?>" />
                            <td><input type="submit" value="Add" id="add"  width="100%"></td>
                            <td><input type="submit" value="Rmv" id="rmv" width="100%"></td></br>
                        <?php echo form_close(); ?>

                 </tr> 

                 <?php 
                 $i=$i+1;}
                echo '</table>';
                ?>
                </div>

                </div>
                 </div>
                 <div class="col-sm-4">
                    <div class="well">
                        <h4>Cart</h4>
                        Total Rs:<input type="text" value="" id="total"></br><br>
                        <input type="submit" value="Checkout" id="chk_out">

                    </div>


                 </div>
                 </div>

                <?php
                }
            echo "</div>";
        }
        ?>
        </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

And my model

```
<?php

if (!defined('BASEPATH'))
exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Product_database extends CI_Model {

public function show_all_data() {
    $this->db->select('*');
    $this->db->from('productlist');
    $query = $this->db->get();
    if ($query->num_rows() > 0) {
        return $query->result();
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}

}
?>
```

Comment: `echo json_econde($yourArray);`, or better yet, provide your code. What have tried? What does it do? What it should do instead?

Comment: The question is not clear. Do you have the issues with fetching AJAX data, or you don't understand how to interact with Database in codeigniter? Can you clarify the question?

Comment: show your controller code

Comment: I have made a data base containing id, name , price and am giving input for quantity, in the controller i have made a new variable to compute quantity*price to calculate total so how can i display name, quantity, price and total after clicking a button  in the same page using ajax

Comment: controller: Welcome.php

Comment: I have added my code above, so suggest me how can i do that, i want to display it below total in the cart section

Answer (score 0):

In place of `echo $total` you can put this code  :

```
 $total= array('total'=> $total); 
 $youarray=array_merge($data, $total);
 echo json_econde($youarray,true);
```

Comment: and parse json in your ajax success

Comment: if i only want to display total in the view then how can i proceed

Comment: what come in after json parse res variable

Comment: after res parse alert(res.total);